# Let $f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ be a polynomial whose roots are all negative integers. If $a + b + c + d = 2009,$ find $d.$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let $f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ be a polynomial whose roots are all negative integers. If $a + b + c + d = 2009,$ find $d.$

---

How should I approach this problem? I have tried to think of a way I could plug some value of $x$ in, but they haven't given us anything about that so that wouldn't work...how should I do it?

Comment: Have you reviewed [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) and the rational root theorem?  They relate the roots to the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: **Hint:** $2010=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 67$.

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed Vieta's formulas and the rational root theorem. @Batominovski: how would that help. I don't see a -1 anywhere...

Comment: What is $f(1)$?

Comment: 1+a+b+c+d=1+2009=2010. But how does that help us...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the roots be $-n_1\geq-n_2\geq-n_3\geq-n_4$ where $0<n_1\leq n_2\leq n_3\leq n_4$ are positive integers. Then $f(x)=(x+n_1)(x+n_2)(x+n_3)(x+n_4)$

$$f(1)=1+a+b+c+d=2010\\\implies(1+n_1)(1+n_2)(1+n_3)(1+n_4)=2\times3\times5\times67\\\implies n_1=1,n_2=2,n_3=4,n_4=66\implies d=n_1n_2n_3n_4=528$$

The solution is unique as any other factorization of $2010$ (eq:$1\times5\times6\times 67$) implies $1+n_1=1$. However, $n_1>0$ and hence, this case does not arise.

Comment: Just to add : the $n_i$ values follow from the fact that if any of the two $n_i$ were the same, the LHS would have a square factor, while the RHS is square free. Thus, none of the $n_i$ are the same. Now the next line follows.